# Spark slaves don't reconnect

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using a standalone cluster of Spark 1.1.0. When I restart master, slaves don't reconnect automatically and appear in the list of workers in Spark UI only after manual restart of each slave. As far as I remember, they used to reconnect in 0.8.

Is it intended change in the behaviour or a bug? Or maybe there's configuration option I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute ./sbin/start-all.sh and ./sbin/stop-all.sh.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I mean that I never see that slave reconnected automatically. Since ver 0.9 (not sure about previous versions), edit /conf/slaves and just exec start-all.sh or stop-all.sh to manage cluster, instead of manual restart of each slave.

Comment: No problem at all and thank you again. Actually I've used these scripts quite a few times :). The problem is that they do rsync and all that stuff, so restarting only hanged master would be much faster.